# how can I scan jTextArea to arraylist or 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a `jTextArea` have this values `[1,3,5,5,5,6],[5,1,4,3,3,3],[3,5,6,5,5,4]`

My question is how can I put the data from this jTextArea to 2d array or Arraylist?

My code:

```
public void toList(JTextArea textArea){

    ArrayList<String>arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jTextArea1.getText())) ;   
    arrList.stream().forEach((jh) -> {
       System.out.println(jh);
    });
}
```

but it returns nothing for output.

Comment: Split the `String` from the `JTextArea` first into the blocks that you want.  In fact, how do you want the data stored?

Comment: it depends what you want string or int arrays?

Comment: I need in arraylist or 2d array. I write method to convert from arraylisti to 2d array . so each one work with me  arraylist or 2darray

Comment: int 2d array better for me

Comment: I try ti splite as String [] arrayOfLines = txt.split("\n"); but not work

Comment: *Code Snippet* is for code which can be run/used by browser (like JavaScript, HTML, CSS) so don't use it for Java (it is not the same as JavaScript). Use *Code Sample* instead which is marked as `{}` in editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the `String` down into it's individual components

```
[1,3,5,5,5,6]
[5,1,4,3,3,3] 
[3,5,6,5,5,4]
```

Then break each "block" down into a series of individual numbers

```
1
3
5
5
5
6
```

And so on, for example...

```
    // Test value
    String text = "[1,3,5,5,5,6],[5,1,4,3,3,3],[3,5,6,5,5,4]";
    // Break down the outter blocks [...]
    String[] blocks = text.split("],");
    // Build the array....
    String[][] blocksArray = new String[blocks.length][];
    for (int index = 0; index < blocks.length; index++) {
        // Get the next block [...]
        String block = blocks[index];
        // Remove the brackets [ and ]
        block = block.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        // Break the numbers apart....
        String[] elements = block.split(",");
        // Apply the numbers to the block array
        blocksArray[index] = elements;
    }
```

Using...

```
    for (String[] block : blocksArray) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(block));
    }
```

I get...

```
[1, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6]
[5, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4]
```

Note `Arrays.toString` is adding the `[` and `,` and `]`

Comment: tnaks fir help but I test that the output is 
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]

Comment: the is the input in my textare 
[[0, 5, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1], [5, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1]]

Comment: and for this input 

[[0, 5, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1], [5, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1], [5, 4, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1]]
exatc ??

Comment: That's not what you posted in you original question.

Comment: You need to remove the leading `[` and trailing `]`, you could use `String#subString`

Comment: sorry I have a headache I forget the symbole[ in the first u can modifier the code ??

Comment: ? You don't know how to use `String#subString` ?

Comment: no problem to get text from jTextArea in java I do thats String h=jTextArea.gettext() but not worl

Comment: As I said, you need to remove the leading `[` and trailing `]` from the text from the text area, `String#subString` can do this, give it a try.  Then the rest of the code will work for you

Comment: Well, `String`s are zero indexed, so you want every after and including the second character (`1`) up to the second last character `length() - 2`...

Comment: you can give me example plz